# Blank screenshots while using Codeception with Laravel module enabled

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, codeception

I'm running Selenium WebDriver 2.40 on my Mint 16 box. No remote, no VM, plain running. But then when I try capturing a screenshot of page for debug purposes via Codeception, I get white image, both with Firefox and Google Chrome driver.

How to fix it?

EDIT: Similar also occurs with PhantomJS driver, but it's transparent image instead of white image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because I used Laravel4 module, which bypassed PhantomJS stuff.

Comment: so how can I use both?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy You can use Codeception + Selenium + PhantomJS in Laravel 4, just don't load Laravel4 module.

Comment: This will also happen with PhantomJS and Laravel5 module. This can save you a lot of time and headache.